# why conditional check for define.amd and module.exports and when do the conditions pass ?

Tags: javascript

hey guys i am very new to js and basically i am trying to learn practical js by digging a few js plugins online and also reading good books . now i was digging through the source of a plugin([tinyscroll.js](https://github.com/wieringen/tinyscrollbar/blob/master/lib/tinyscrollbar.js#L386)) and saw the following lines of code :

```
  if(typeof define == 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(function(){ return tinyscrollbar; });
    }
    else if(typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = tinyscrollbar;
    }
    else {
        window.tinyscrollbar = tinyscrollbar;
    }
```

i have seem similar lines of code in alot of plugins , as a bigginer these lines of code don't make alot of sense to me , as in i know its a combination of if else statements but , i have no idea as to what use these line are gonna be. my educated guess is(and also after a little bit of testing, that the condition that passes is the last `else` .) . so why the 2 previos conditions ?.

i googled difine.amd and got a bunch of links that said "Asynchronous module definition(AMD)" and the following explanation :

> Asynchronous module definition (AMD) is a JavaScript specification
>   that defines an API for defining code modules and their dependencies,
>   and loading them asynchronously if desired.

but i am still in tangles .

can somebody just tell me why the following lines of if and else if ?

```
if(typeof define == 'function' && define.amd) {
            define(function(){ return tinyscrollbar; });
        }
        else if(typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
            module.exports = tinyscrollbar;
        }
```

Thank you .

Comment: @downvoter ? why did you downvote me ? did u have a very good reason to do so ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old question but I think it's worth answering because this question usually springs out when a programmer have a first look at a javascript library and try to figure out what is in the guts of the library and understand the code.
There are slight variations to the sequence you gave, one that I like is:

```
if (typeof define === "function" & define.amd )
  this.myLib = myLib, define(myLib);
else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports)
  module.exports = myLib;
else
  this.myLib = myLib;
```

The first thing to understand is that a library can be developed to be deployed in different environments: in an amd loader, within a "*javascript machine*" (think node.js) or in a browser.

So this code is basically a way to export a javascript library through a precedence schema.

In my code if "**define**" is defined and we are on a amd environment then I'll export my library both with define (as in `define(myLib)`) and will add it to "**this**". That's usually what you would do to export a module in AMD. Require.js has a good tutorial on AMD, take a look at:
http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd

Then if there is "**module**" is and "**module.exports**" exists then I'll add my library to module.exports. This is usually what is needed if you're deploying your library in a node.js module. You canfind an introductory tutorial to module.export here: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Otherwise, I'll just add my library to "**this**", wich is usually the case when you're just adding a .js library via a `<script scr="...">` tag in a web page. In this case one could have used `window.myLib = myLib` but I prefer to use `this.myLib = myLib` instead.

Comment: Thanks :D i'lllook into this